# Cmd+R not working, 5 min startup time

Tags: macos

I have a 10.6.8, all of a sudden takes 5 min to start up. I can't get into the utilities, as I hold cmd and R with no effect. No time machine on this computer.
There are 700 Mb free on the hard disk. I changed the keyboard with a wired one as it wouldn't see the wireless anymore. The mouse pointer stalls then jumps to the edge of the screen.Different mouse doing the same. Once started, all apps running smooth.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

OS X 10.6.8 does not have a recovery partition. First backup all your user data before preceding. Try starting the computer in safe mode: Shut down the computer and wait 10 seconds; Press the power button and press the Shift key. This will perform a file consistency check and disable other functions on your computer. Open Disk Utility and check the S.M.A.R.T status. It seems as if your hard drive is failing.

Comment: Good answer. Also the OP may know holding the Shift button on boot as a "Safe Boot".